# Geth is always 100 blocks behind and never starts syncing states

Tags: go-ethereum

Geth seems to be always near reaching the highest block but never actually reaching the same number, so it never starts syncing states. `knownStates` is always 0.

Using `geth attach` there is always a small difference between `currentBlock` and `highestBlock`:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 12903364,
  highestBlock: 12903434,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 12900170
}
```

BTW **I am running an SSD**, so no need to suggest that.

Comment: because geth has not synced yet. when you sync you will see `false` as output and not the counters

Comment: you didn't even download the first account of the state yet

Comment: How come "I" didn't download the first state, when it says currentBlock 12M? What should I do to have it download states?

Comment: because when you download the state you will have `knownState` set to something larger than 0, but apparently you are downloading via state snapshots, anyway this node hasn't synced yet

Comment: Aynthing I can do to change this? Current block always seems 100 blocks behind no matter when I look

Comment: get an SSD disk with M2 PCI express v3 or v4 interface, `geth` executes about 1000 random IOPs per second

Comment: I am using an SSD. I was using it as an external disk, and now that I'm using it internally it is still always 100 blocks behind. Any more wisdom?

Comment: these low end SATA SSD disks are slow, you will have to get a lot of patience and wait, check out the disk growth, current size is 400GB if you sync in 1 day. If you sync in many days for each day add like 500MB of garbage data (these are intermediate states) to these 400GB to estimate how much time is left for completion